# How to Get current day of the week in a dropdaownlist in c#

Tags: c#, drop-down-menu

i Have a dropdown list in which the 7 days (monday to sunday) are there. i want to in a manner that the current day of the week should be shown by default in the drop down list. Here is my code

```
private void ddldays_Bind() 
{     
     this.ddldays.DataSource = GetWeekDays();
     this.ddldays.DataBind();
}

private List<DayOfWeek> GetWeekDays()
{            
     return Enum.GetValues(typeof(DayOfWeek)).Cast<DayOfWeek>().ToList();
}
```

Comment: This may be off-topic. But, question aside, I am sure I read such question about DropdownList containing day of week for the third or fourth time today... You may find useful posts if you search, Sir...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Select the item in the dropdownlist by value:

```
ddldays.SelectedValue = DateTime.Today.DayOfWeek
```